# $M$ is a finitely generated $R$-module if and only if

Tags: ring-theory, modules, finitely-generated

**When I say module here I mean a left module**

I am trying to prove that if there is a surjective homomorphism of $R$-modules $\phi : R^n \rightarrow M $ then $M$ is finitely generated as an $R$-module.

I start by defining $x_1= \phi (1,0,...,0) , x_2 = \phi (0,1,0,...,0), ..., x_n = \phi (0,0,...,0,1) $. Then $x_i \in M $ for all $i$.

I want to show that the span of these $x_i $ is $M$.

So if $m \in M$ then $m=\phi (r_1,...,r_n )$ for some $r_1,...,r_n \in R $.
I think then we should be able to say that $m= r_1 x_1+...+r_nx_n=(r_1.1,...,r_n.1 )$ but are we able to say that $r_i.1=r_i $?

If not then am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: $1$ is the multiplicative identity of the ring $R,$ so naturally $r\cdot 1=r$ for all $r\in R.$

Comment: Are we saying here that the action on $R$ as an $R$-module is just the same as multiplication within the ring $R$?

Comment: That is usually the convention taken, yes.

Comment: @Ben  it’s not even a convention. It is the _definition_ for the action of the regular right module $R_R$, and free modules are just direct sums of copies of that module.